# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function on bool

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I know this answer has been answered already but it seems like I couldn't understand anything in my case (I'm still very new to web developing, learning frontend since this october and I jumped onto php at the start of this month).
My function is supposed to check if user is logged in and I couldn't understand the answers I read for my problem cause it seems like in the answers I found, the functions weren't custom? I might be wrong and I hope if I am, you can laugh about it.

So, to get a bit of context, I encounter this error when I try to call the function "check_logged_in()" in one of my controllers, this controller in question (it's called Upload) extends the main Controller from my core folder (and I triple checked if my init file has required it so I can use it globally).
Then I call a custom function from the main controller to load models if needed (in this case, I need to load my user model to get access to the "check_logged_in()" function since it's written there).
And this is where thing happen. I'll provide a bit of code so you guys can understand what I'm saying.

The Upload controller

```
<?php

class Upload extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        header("location:" . ROOT . "upload/image");
        die;
    }
    function image()
    {
        $user = $this->loadModel("user");
        
        if(!$result = $user->check_logged_in()){
            header("location:" . ROOT . "login");
            die;
        }

        $data['page_title'] = "Upload";
        $this->view("upload", $data);
    }
}
```

The main Controller

```
<?php

class Controller
{
    protected function view($view, $data = [])
    {
        if (file_exists("../app/views/" . $view . ".php")) {
            include "../app/views/" . $view . ".php";
        } else {
            include "../app/views/404.php";
        }
    }
    protected function loadModel($model)
    {
        if (file_exists("../app/model/" . $model . ".php")) {
            include "../app/model/" . $model . ".php";
            return $model = new $model();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And the bit of code from the user model that is called

```
<?php

class User
{
    function check_logged_in()
    {

        $DB = new Database();
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_url'])) {

            $arr['user_url'] = $_SESSION['user_url'];

            $query = "select * from users where url_address = :user_url limit 1";
            $data = $DB->read($query, $arr);
            if (is_array($data)) {
                //logged in
                $_SESSION['user_name'] = $data[0]->username;
                $_SESSION['user_url'] = $data[0]->url_address;

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your time mates, I hope my noob self is clear enough for you to understand ^^'

Comment: `$this->loadModel("user")` must have returned `false`, instead of an actual instance of the `User` class. Which in turn likely means, the `file_exists` call in there did not actually find the file you are looking for there.

Comment: You've stripped the error message and it's no longer useful to find the error. What is the function being called and what is the line where that happens? I understand you need some experience to know what error messages mean, but that doesn't imply they're useless.

Comment: On a side note,  beware that `select * from users ... limit 1` without an `order by` clause will return an arbitrary row (not even a properly randomised one).

Comment: @CBroe, yeah the loadModel is supposed to be returned false so I can be redirected to the login page since I'm not connected, but I get this error message instead, I'm kinda lost I think I need to learn a bit more before going into php coding.

Comment: @Álvaro González The function being called is check_logged_in() on line 14, this is where the error happens :s

Comment: If `loadModel` returned false, then `$user` is false now. So you are effectively trying to call `false->check_logged_in()` now, which makes no sense - as the error message told you, `false` does not have any such method, it is not even an object. _"is supposed to be returned false so I can be redirected to the login page since I'm not connected"_ - what does _that_ have to do, with the fact that you at least need to load the necessary class files? Makes no sense whatsoever. You _need_ an instance of your `User` class, before you can call its `check_logged_in` method.

Comment: @CBroe I have no clue about the logic behind php to be honest, I didn't write this code myself and I followed this tutorial : https://youtu.be/mK7CiJeYOwI?list=RDCMUCItTNvcjpPzzMi92VRq3zNw&t=9152

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking for the correct value of the $user variable should fix the error.

```
...
    function image()
    {
        $user = $this->loadModel("user");
        
        if(!$user || !$user->check_logged_in()){ // Here
            header("location:" . ROOT . "login");
            die;
        }

        $data['page_title'] = "Upload";
...
```

Then on `$user` is `false` condition will be
`!false || !false->check_logged_in()` which will lead to `true`.

Otherwise on `$user` is `User`:
`!(object User) || !(object User)->check_logged_in()` will call `User::check_logged_in()` method.